# Adding a C++ UWP class library to a C# UWP class library

Tags: c#, uwp

If I have two UWP C# class libraries in my solution then I can add one as a reference to the other. But if I try to add a UWP C++ class library to a UWP C# class library I get the error pop up

> A reference to 'ProjectName' could not be added

and the same error happens with a UWP C++ static library.

Is it possible to add a UWP C++ class library to a UWP C# class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard UWP C++ class library is not visible for UWP C# class library.

To access your UWP C++ class library from app/library written in any Windows Runtime-compatible language compile it as ["Windows Runtime Component"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-cpp).

The most simple way to do that is to recreate project with UWP C++ "Window Runtime Component" template.

Also you can manually change `Project Configuration -> C/C++ -> General -> Consume Windows Runtime Extension -> Yes(/ZW)`. Change `_WIN_DLL` to `_WINRT_DLL` in Preprocessor definitions.